# I want to see the textarea in Rails JUST as javascript does

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that allows a user to submit HTML, and I just want to make a few changes to the text (e.g. replace a company name with one in Active Record), and then replace the HTML inside of a textarea. However, it's not playing too well. For whatever reason, trying to replace the textarea with the contents that were submitted in its POST request does not work. Nothing happens.

Here's my view form:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <%= form_tag(convert_email_template_path(format: :js), method: :post, :authenticity_token => true, id: 'importEmailForm', remote: true) do %>
            <%= text_area_tag 'import_email', nil, rows: 10, placeholder: "Paste the headers of your email here.", class: "form-control" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Import'.html_safe, '#', onclick: "importEmail();", class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
</div>
```

So basically, importEmail() looks like this:

```
function importEmail() {
   setTimeout(function () { 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $("#importEmailForm").attr("action"),
      data: $("#importEmailForm").serialize(), 
    });
  }, 100)
};
```

which basically submits the form in the view. I need to capture this POST data, make a change or two, and then proceed with replacing textarea with the modified contents.

Now if I do this in plain javascript, this works fine:

```
#views/templates/convert_email.js.erb

var sourceBody = $('#import_email').val();
var start_position = sourceBody.indexOf("<html>");
var stop_position = sourceBody.indexOf("</html>");
var html = sourceBody.substring(start_position, stop_position);
var fixed_html = html.replace(/(=\n)/g, '');

// Grab body.    
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-iframe")[0]
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

// get the element in question
const input = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// Before pasting data, let's make sure the code view is turned OFF.
if ($('textarea').froalaEditor('codeView.isActive') == true) {
    $('textarea').froalaEditor('codeView.toggle');
}

// dispatch keyboard events
input.innerHTML = fixed_html;

// Close modal.
$('#Modal').modal('toggle')
```

But if capture this POST data with `params[:import_email]`, and do something like this:

```
#controllers/templates.rb
body = params[:import_email]
@body = body.gsub("=\n", "")
```

and pass that to the javascript view.

```
#views/templates/convert_email.js.erb
// Grab body.    
var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("fr-iframe")[0]
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

// get the element in question
const input = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// log codeview status
var codeView = 0

// Before pasting data, let's make sure the code view is turned OFF.
if ($('textarea').froalaEditor('codeView.isActive') == false) {
    codeView = 0;
    $('textarea').froalaEditor('codeView.toggle');
} else {
    codeView = 1;
}

function
// dispatch keyboard events
input.innerHTML = "<%= @body %>";

resizeFroala();

// Close modal.
$('#Modal').modal('toggle')
```

Nothing happens. Perhaps there's a way to treat a textarea as source code or something?

Using the first method (javascript only), this is what `fixed_html` looks like in the console:

[image: javascript console output of what was submitted]

I want to get `@body` to look like this, but in order for me to do that, I have to do this in the controller:

```
body = params[:import_email]
@body = body.gsub("=\r", "\r").gsub("\n", "").gsub("\r", "").gsub("\t", "")
```

but trying to write this to the console looks like this:

[image: rails version of submitting data]

Sorry for any confusion. Hope this makes sense. I just basically want to do what works flawlessly in Javascript, but in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Think I finally figured it out. Didn't realize rails used `<%== %>` in addition to `<%= %>`

Changed my code to:

`input.innerHTML = "<%== j @body %>";`

and this did the trick. Wow.